# Dictionary value travel

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

I need to travel values of the dictionary in a single for loop to add and compare values. Here is my dictionary.

I am aware of iterating dictionary based on key but not sure if we can iterate based on an index of values of the dictionary.

```
dict = {
        0: [1,2,3,4,7]
        1: [2,4,6,9,0]
        2: [4,6,8,2,1]

            }
```

if I iterate over key-value, it will not help me. I need to execute for loop for each index of the value list.

Assumption: length of list for each dictionary key will be the same.

```
Total   highest_class
7       2
12      2
17      2
15      1
8       0
```

Basically, sum all number from the value of the dictionary at the same index and also return which key has the highest number.

Comment: You can't use a list instead of a dict at first ?

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @Dorian Turba, I can not use list because I do not know what will be number of keys. Number of keys will be dynamic and it can be any number. One solution is, I can convert it to pandas data frame and do rest of operation but I am thinking if I can achieve using a dictionary that will be great and avoid additional libraries.

Comment: Why your output is 5 line but only 3 line in the dict ?

Comment: @Dorian  That is same as number of elements in the list. exm: for first, 1+2+4 = 7 and 4 is highest which belongs to key 2. thats why it is 7 (sum of first elements) and 2 (key in which 4 belongs to).

Comment: Ok I understand. I don't know how to solve this without "for loop for each index of the value list"

Comment: Check my edit !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
dict = {
        0: [1,2,3,4,7],
        1:  [2,4,6,9,0],
        2:  [4,6,8,2,1]
        }

data = [(sum(item),item.index(max(item))) for item in list(zip(*dict.values()))]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns =['Total', 'highest_class'])
print (df)
```

output:

```
   Total  highest_class
0      7              2
1     12              2
2     17              2
3     15              1
4      8              0
```

EDIT:

```
data = [(sum(item),item.index(max(item))) for item in list(zip(*dict.values()))]

print ('Total', 'highest_class')
for item in data:
    print ("{:<10} {:<10}".format(item[0], item[1]))
```

output:

```
Total highest_class
7          2         
12         2         
17         2         
15         1         
8          0
```

Answer (score 0):

As much as I understood what you want. This might help.

```
mydict = {
        0: [1,2,3,4,7],
        1: [20,4,6,9,0],
        2: [4,6,8,2,1]

            }
maxElement={"highest_class":None,
    "Total":-1
}

for key,value in mydict.items():
    print(sum(value) , maxElement["Total"])
    if sum(value) > maxElement["Total"]:
        maxElement["highest_class"] = key
        maxElement["Total"] = sum(value)

print(maxElement)
```